# fix segmentation fault in trie c++

Tags: c++, trie

I'm using a trie implementation to store and search words in c++ programming language. In using the search() function, I am getting a segmentation fault when searching for a specific word. It seems that the error occurred in checking if the struct is null.

here is the error message:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555b2ff in search (this=0x55555577ee70, 
wordlist=0x55555577ef00, word="a1g6os") at test.cc:30
            if (!pCrawl->children[index])
```

here is the source code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
const int ALPHABET_SIZE = 26; 

struct TrieNode { 
struct TrieNode *children[ALPHABET_SIZE]; 

bool isEndOfWord; 
}; 



struct TrieNode *getNode(void) { 
    struct TrieNode *pNode =  new TrieNode; 
     pNode->isEndOfWord = false; 

    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++) 
        pNode->children[i] = NULL; 

    return pNode; 
} 



void insert(struct TrieNode *root, string key) { 
    struct TrieNode *pCrawl = root; 

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) { 
        int index = key[i] - 'a'; 
        if (!pCrawl->children[index]) 
            pCrawl->children[index] = getNode(); 

        pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index]; 
   } 

   // mark last node as leaf 
   pCrawl->isEndOfWord = true; 
} 

// Returns true if key presents in trie, else 
// false 
bool search(struct TrieNode *root, string key) { 
    struct TrieNode *pCrawl = root; 

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) { 
        int index = key[i] - 'a'; 
        if (!pCrawl->children[index]) 
             return false; 

        pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index]; 
    } 

    return (pCrawl != NULL && pCrawl->isEndOfWord); 
} 

int main() { 
    string keys[] = {"the", "a", "there", 
                "answer", "any", "by", 
                 "bye", "their" }; 
    int n = sizeof(keys)/sizeof(keys[0]); 

    struct TrieNode *root = getNode(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        insert(root, keys[i]); 

    // Search for different keys 
    search(root, "a1g6os")? cout << "Yes\n" : 
                     cout << "No\n"; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The code you show doesn't match the debugger output. The debugger shows a `this` argument, which indicate a member function. None of the function in the code you show are member functions. When creating a [mcve], please make sure it actually exhibits the problem you ask about (and of course that all output you show is from that code).

Comment: You need to check if `pCrawl` is not `nullptr` **before** accessing it's members

Comment: Code is written to only work on lower case letters (ALPHABET_SIZE is 26 and index is offset by 'a'). Yet your search string contains numbers. This will cause access outside of the allocated arrays!

Comment: Also note that something like `key[i] - 'a'` works well with ASCII encoding, but ASCII isn't mandated by the C++ specification. There are other (though not as common) encodings where something like that won't work.

Comment: @JohnnyJohansson  you're right, this trie doesn't support numbers. thank you for pointing out the problem

Comment: `if (!pCrawl->children[index])` causes a out-of-bounds read (a.k.a buffer overflow).  A live test of your code is available at:  https://segfault.stensal.com/a/myH5MWa7EEhfe6TZ

Comment: @stensal i see, how can I prevent this to happen? you can post an answer if you want

Comment: Do not include `<bits/stdc++.h>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both @Some programmer dude and @JohnnyJohansson have pointed out the root cause. The live test showed where the code read the array out-of-bounds. Actually the fix is easy once you understand what happens. The following is the fixed code if you cannot figure it out by yourself.  A live test of it is here [cee.studio](https://cee.studio/2020-05-24.7kFr7DfONRiAG7DZ/RWfOs)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
const int ALPHABET_SIZE = 75; // increase the range

struct TrieNode { 
struct TrieNode *children[ALPHABET_SIZE]; 

bool isEndOfWord; 
}; 



struct TrieNode *getNode(void) { 
    struct TrieNode *pNode =  new TrieNode; 
     pNode->isEndOfWord = false; 

    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++) 
        pNode->children[i] = NULL; 

    return pNode; 
} 



void insert(struct TrieNode *root, string key) { 
    struct TrieNode *pCrawl = root; 

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) { 
        int index = key[i] - '0';  // lower the low bound
        if (!pCrawl->children[index]) 
            pCrawl->children[index] = getNode(); 

        pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index]; 
   } 

   // mark last node as leaf 
   pCrawl->isEndOfWord = true; 
} 

// Returns true if key presents in trie, else 
// false 
bool search(struct TrieNode *root, string key) { 
    struct TrieNode *pCrawl = root; 

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) { 
        int index = key[i] - '0';  // lower the low bound
        if (!pCrawl->children[index]) 
             return false; 

        pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index]; 
    } 

    return (pCrawl != NULL && pCrawl->isEndOfWord); 
} 

int main() { 
    string keys[] = {"the", "a", "there", 
                "answer", "any", "by", 
                 "bye", "their" }; 
    int n = sizeof(keys)/sizeof(keys[0]); 

    struct TrieNode *root = getNode(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        insert(root, keys[i]); 

    // Search for different keys 
    search(root, "a1g6os")? cout << "Yes\n" : 
                     cout << "No\n"; 
    return 0; 
}
```